# Calling code behind function from jquery Side

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How can I do call code-behind function from the client-side?

```
// Code-behind function:
public void CodeBehindFunction(int i)
{
   ...
}
```

I want to call it from client-side...

```
// Client-side call:
$(this). ??
```

Comment: I would recommend you provide some code and otherwise expand on your question or you will get some -1s coming your way...

Answer (score 0):

Correctly you mean you wish to call a server-side routine from client-side code...

I would suggest you force a postback using JavaScript : `__doPostback('CodeBehindFunction',iParameter);` - Then in the Page Init event of your server side code, catch this custom postback by something like..

```
if (Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"] == "CodeBehindFunction")
{
    int i;
    // Try to convert the argument (in the example this is the value of iParameter)
    if (int.TryParse(Request.Params("__EVENTARGUMENT"),out i)
    {
        CodeBehindFunction(i);
    }
}
```

Alternatively use a WebService called through [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax).

Comment: I musn't do postback because a lot of callback function in this page

Comment: Then you should use a WebService and call with jQuery.ajax

Comment: You mean [this kind of Client Callback?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178210.aspx)

Comment: Can you not use that example to do what you need to do?

Comment: I'm using it.In my page I have ui dialog( I load another page in it) when I close ui dialog all of my page's callback function use another pages raisecallback function(normally they used my pages raisecallback function when I open ui dialog then all callback functions use another pages raisecallback function and all parameters be undefined.)..I think if I call "search_button.Attributes["OnClick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "Basla()", "Istek", null, "Hata", true);" in jquery side maybe I solve my problem but I dont know how can I do

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to call CodeBehindFunction(int i) 
but you have to mark the method as webmethod and static:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void CodeBehindFunction(int i)
{
   ...
}
```

then call it from js

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/yourPage.aspx/CodeBehindFunction",
                data: "{'i':'"+num+"'}", //PUT DATA HERE
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) { 

                 }
            })
```

** yourPage.aspx is the page where CodeBehindFunction method is declared